# Subquery in Lambda

Tags: c#, sql, linq, lambda

I am getting

here is my query of sql server to which i tried to convert into

```
select * from Permission Where PermissionId in(select PermissionId from RoleDetail where RoleId =1)
```

here is my initial lambda subquery

```
from p in Permissions
    let rde = from rd in RoleDetails
        select rd.PermissionId
        where p.PermissionId ==1
        select p
```

but its showing me only one record attached with that role , but actuaaly it has 5 permissions please help.

Comment: What type of `rde` variable? Maybe it needs to be lambda like `rde.Contains(r => r.PermissionId == 1)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try this?  Instead of trying to use `.Contains()`, just do a join on the two tables...

```
from p in Permissions
join rd in RoleDetails on p.PermissionId equals rd.PermissionId
where rd.RoleId == 1
select p;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Join`:-

```
var result = from p in Permissions
             join rd in RoleDetails.Where(x => x.RoleId == 1)
             on p.PermissionId equals rd.PermissionId 
             select p;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing wrong do like this:

```
from p in Permissions
    let rde = (from rd in RoleDetails
               where rd.RoleId ==1
               select rd.PermissionId)
where p.PermissionId = rde
select p
```

See [LET usage HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383976.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Using join (proposed in the other answers) is better, but to fix your query, you should filter `rde` on `RoleId = 1` then filter `Permissions` with `rde`:

```
from p in Permissions
    let rde = from rd in RoleDetails
        where rd.RoleId == 1           // filter RoleId = 1
        select rd.PermissionId
    where rde.Contains(p.PermissionId) // rde should contain p.PermissionId
    select p
```